# Solve the recurrence relation $a_{n+2} =2a_{n+1} - a_n$ with $a_0 =0$ and $a_1 =1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

The book I am using for my Combinatorics course is Combinatorics:Topics, Techniques, and Algorithms.

Solve the recurrence relation $a_{n+2} =2a_{n+1} - a_n$ with $a_0 =0$ and $a_1 =1$

This is my rough proof to this question. I was wondering if anybody can look over it and see if I made a mistake or if there is a simpler way of doing this problem. I want to thank you ahead of time it is greatly appreciated.So lets begin:

Proof:

[image]

Comment: Everything well done. At the end, it is easy to check by substitution that you are right. By theory there is a unique solution, and $n$ works, so it is the solution.

Comment: That looks as simple as it gets.  It is correct.  Another approach is to use $Z$-transforms, but this is not significantly simpler, if at all.

Comment: You have a typo in your solution; you start by saying "Given that $a_0=1$", but then proceed as if $a_0=0$ as in the problem statement...

Answer (score 6):

This method is a bit faster...:

$a_{n} - a_{n-1} = a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}=....= a_1-a_0=1$. Thus:

$a_n = (a_n-a_{n-1})+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})+\cdots + (a_1-a_0) + a_0 = n$

Comment: Nice solution. (+1)